# Year of 401k contribution for last paycheck?

Tags: united-states, 401k, contribution, paycheck

I am getting my next paycheck on Jan 2nd, 2020. The paycheck covers work performed in 2019. Will the paycheck go towards my 2019 or 2020 401K contribution limit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

W-2 and 401(k) are based on the `Pay Date`, **not** the `Period Beginning` and `Period Ending` dates.

Split things up would be a big complication.

Individual wage and 1099 employees always(?) whether they know it or not, use the cash method of accounting. According to [IRS Publication 538](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p538.pdf) "Under the cash method, you include in your gross income all items of income you actually or constructively receive during the tax year."

Comment: do you have a source for this?

Comment: @jgozal my own experience.  Individual wage and 1099 employees always(?) whether they know it or not, use the cash method of accounting.  According to https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p538.pdf "Under the cash method, you include in your gross income
all items of income you actually or constructively receive during the tax year."

Comment: thanks @RonJohn, I only ask because my CFP told me the opposite: that my employer is required to withhold the amount from the check, so if my pay period is from Dec 16 -31, it will be considered a 2019 contribution. Hence my confusion. I will ask him as well to provide some support as well.

Comment: The IRS article you reference makes a lot of sense in terms of how the IRS views receipt of income. I wish there was more discussion about W2 employees.

Comment: this article from the balance also confirms your response https://www.thebalancesmb.com/end-of-year-employee-paychecks-which-year-s-taxes-3974570

Comment: @jgozal: my experience: I once made the whole year's worth of 401(k) contributions on January 1 (which were counted for the new year, not the previous year), on a paycheck that was "for work performed" in December of the previous year but dated on January 1 because the company paid on the 1st of the month at that time